# Refreshing the activity

Tags: android

i am making the app in which user will be able to c the routine services available to him . For this i am using the website where the admin will be able to update the services . User from android will be able to get the list of services by parsing the xml file available on the server .

The thing i am wondering about is that is there any way the activity automatically refresh itself and user can c the updates done in the services by admin.

Thanks

Comment: Like [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) for notification? Refreshing data then should be simple I guess, just re-query services and act on new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do some job on a regular basis, you should have a look at the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). The general scheme is the following:

```
 //This handler launches the task
 private final Handler handler = new Handler();

 //This is a task which will be executed
 private class RefreshTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
     protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
         //Do refreshing here
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
         //Update UI here
     }
 }

 //This is a Runnable, which will launch the task
 private final Runnable refreshRunnable = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         new RefreshTask(param1, param2).execute();
         handler.postDelayed(refreshRunnable, TIME_DELAY);
     }
 };
```

Then you call `handler.post(refreshRunnable)` when you want to start updates. To cancel them, call `handler.removeCallbacks(refreshRunnable)`. I should note, of course, that I haven't tested this code, but it should give a general idea what to do.

Comment: I would also add a member mServerTask variable to my activity and before to start new execution i will see if the old task still running