# Pushing Data to Application

Tags: android, push

I am new to developing android application. I need some guide as to how can I push a update to my application from my server. I want it to work something like Twitter where I can push a update of text and pictures to my application with a standard display format. Need some guide to how can I get this started.

I have seen through tutorials on push notification but that is not what I wanted. I want to be able to display the text on the received notification into my application.

Thanks

Comment: Is this article what you want to know? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252065/refreshing-activity-on-receiving-gcm-push-notification

Answer (score 1):

You can use websocket for pushing data from server to application.

Your application should open websocket connection with server. Then bi-di communication can be done between application and server.

Sample java websocket client can be found below link.
https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket